# How to create multiple backgrounds in one CSS declaration with no overlap so transparency on ends shows?

Tags: css

I have a div in CSS which is to show a piece of tape.

[image]

The problem is that the background in the middle is overlapping and appearing on both ends of the tape, so the transparency that should be at the ends of the tape div is not there.

Here is my CSS.

```
.tape {
background-image: url(../graphics/tapeleft.png), url(../graphics/taperight.png), url(../graphics/tapemiddle.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
background-position: left, right, center;

font-size: 1.05em;
height:32px;
min-width:75px;
line-height:32px;
text-align:center;
border:0 solid #000000;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
display:inline-block;

color: black;
}

.tape span { padding-left:16px; padding-right:16px; }
```

How do I stop the middle background from appearing beneath the background on the ends, while having the three backgrounds in one div? I have tried using background-clip and background-origin but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Post a working code snippet, with the image's in question, so we get the right markup along with your CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/desbest/Lgbdud6f/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pseudo element for the repeated image, as you can't set both a start and an end offset for it.

```css
body {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.tape {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/vVnpGzx.png'),
                    url('http://i.imgur.com/Po3AT0u.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left, right;
  font-size: 1.05em;
  height: 32px;
  min-width: 75px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}
.tape::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 8px;               /*  start offset  */
  right: 8px;              /*  end offset    */
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/7aGUUgo.png') center;
  z-index: -1
}

.tape span {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tape">
  <span>$60 annual revenue</span>
</div>
```